# PHP - Adding 2 div to a foreach loop every 4 times with ACF Repeater

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF Repeater field i'd like to output as an accordion grid, like so:

```html
<div class="intro row">
  <div class="item item-1">name 1</div>
  <div class="item item-2">name 2</div>
  <div class="item item-3">name 3</div>
  <div class="item item-4">name 4</div>
</div>

<div class="expanded row">      
  <div class="expand" id="item-1">expanded info 1</div>
  <div class="expand" id="item-2">expanded info 2</div>
  <div class="expand" id="item-3">expanded info 3</div>
  <div class="expand" id="item-4">expanded info 4</div>
</div>

<div class="intro row">
  <div class="item item-5">name 5</div>
  <div class="item item-6">name 6</div>
  <div class="item item-7">name 7</div>
  <div class="item item-8">name 8</div>
</div>

<div class="expanded row">      
  <div class="expand" id="item-5">expanded info 5</div>
  <div class="expand" id="item-6">expanded info 6</div>
  <div class="expand" id="item-7">expanded info 7</div>
  <div class="expand" id="item-8">expanded info 8</div>
</div>
```

I can group the initial row fine, it's just the second "expanded" row i'm having trouble with. How can I repeat and group the second row of 4 correctly in the same loop?  My current PHP:

```html
<?php // check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('features') ):
  // loop through the rows of data

  // add a counter
  $count = 0;
  $group = 0;
  
  while ( have_rows('features') ) : the_row(); 
   
    
 $name = get_sub_field('feature_name');
 $expandedInfo = get_sub_field('feature_info');

    if ($count % 4 == 0) {
      $group++;
      ?>
        <div class="intro row">
      <?php 
    }
    ?>
    <div class="item item-<?php echo $count; ?>">
      <?php echo $name ?>
    </div><!-- item-->
    
   
    <?php 
      if ($count % 4 == 3) {
        ?>
          </div><!-- intro-->
        <?php 
      }
      $count++;
    endwhile;
else :
  // no rows found
endif;

?>
```

Comment: `if ($count % 2 == 0)` then add the expanded class !

Comment: I'm not sure that will work will it? The initial 4 have to repeated again with different classes

Comment: you mean that you want the very first ( second div ) take the class expanded ?

Comment: If we're talking about row of the loop, it has to be repeated and grouped twice - so ABCD(intro) ABCD(expand) EFGH(intro) EFGH(expand) if that makes sense?

Comment: i can't get the point , you want to get the exact result as same as the provided snippet in your question ?

Comment: Apologies, not the best at explaining myself! The output of the PHP needs to match the HTML snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second 'expanded' row can be done so that you store each count (item-1,item-2) in an array or just traverse through all the count when you close the intro row.

```
<?php
if ($count % 4 == 3) {
    ?>
      </div><!-- intro-->
      <div class="expanded row">
         <?php 
          $start = $count-3; 
          // if $count is 4, $start will be 1, and the $i will go to 4
          // if $count is 8, $start will be 5
         for($i=$start;$i<=$count;$i++){
           echo '<div class="expand" id="item-' . $i . '"></div>';
         } ?>
      </div>
    <?php 
  }
```

This is just an example. I would suggest you to store each $count in an array and then use the count($array) to get the number of them. After you have traversed the array, reset it.

**The Array Approach**

```
<?php // check if the repeater field has rows of data
  if( have_rows('features') ):
  // loop through the rows of data

  // add a counter
  $count = 0;
  $group = 0;
  // Content Array
  $content_array = array();
  while ( have_rows('features') ) : the_row(); 


    $name = get_sub_field('feature_name');
    $expandedInfo = get_sub_field('feature_info');
    // Adding the Expanded Info
    $content_array[ 'item-' . $count ] = $expandedInfo;
    if ($count % 4 == 0) {
      $group++;
     ?>
      <div class="intro row">
     <?php 
    }
   ?>
   <div class="item item-<?php echo $count; ?>">
    <?php echo $name ?>
   </div><!-- item-->


   <?php 
     if ($count % 4 == 3) {
    ?>
      </div><!-- intro-->
      <div class="expanded row">
         <?php 

         foreach( $content_array as $item_id => $expanded_info ) {

          echo '<div class="expanded" id="' . $item_id . '">';
          echo $expanded_info;
          echo '</div>';

         } ?>
      </div>
    <?php 
    // Resetting the Array
    $content_array = array();
  }
  $count++;
  endwhile;
else :
// no rows found
endif;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works in terms of the right grouping but when I echo the content of the row in the format: '<div class="expand" id="item-' . $i . '">' . $expandedContent . '</div>'

It only repeats the data from the last row for each one

Comment: I have updated my answer with the array approach and the expanded info. See if it works for you. Be aware of the declaration of the array before the while loop.

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can't test it right now, but I think something like that should work.

```
<?php // check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('features') ):
  // loop through the rows of data

  // add a counter
  $count = 0;
  $group = 0;
  $array = array();

  while ( have_rows('features') ) : the_row(); 

    $name = get_sub_field('feature_name');
    $expandedInfo = get_sub_field('feature_info');
    if ($count % 4 == 0) {
      $group++;
      ?>
        <div class="intro row">
      <?php 
    }
    ?>
    <div class="item item-<?php echo $count; ?>">
      <?php echo $name ?>
    </div><!-- item-->


    <?php 
        array_push($array, $expandedInfo);
      if ($count % 4 == 3) {
        ?>
          </div><!-- intro-->
          <div class="expanded row">
        <?php
        for ($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) { 
            echo '<div class="expand" id="item-'.$i + 1.'">'.$array[$i].'</div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
      }
      $count++;
    endwhile;
else :
  // no rows found
endif;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works in terms of the right grouping but when I echo the content of the row in the format: '<div class="expand" id="item-'.$array[$i].'">' . $expandContent . '</div>' It only repeats the data from the last row for each group

Comment: Then you should stock the `$expandContent` of each row along with the `$count`.

Comment: On closer inspection there seems to be a problem with the expand ID count, item-'.$i + 1.'

Comment: Could you describe me the problem ?

Comment: It seems to be echoing the expanded content again instead of the count number

Answer (score 0):

okey, lets see ,

using variables to store your templates may helps a lot in this context ,

as follow :

```
$intro = '';
$expanded = '';
while (have_rows('features')) :

    the_row();

    if ($count % 4 == 0) {
        $group++;

        $intro .= '<div class="intro row">';
        $expanded .= '<div class="expanded row">';

    }
    $intro .= '<div class="item item-' . $count . '"></div><!-- item-->';
    $expanded .= '<div class="expand" id="item-' . $count . '"></div>';

    if ($count % 4 == 3) {
        $intro = '</div><!-- intro-->';
        $expanded = '</div><!-- intro-->';
    }
    $count++;
endwhile;
```

I've made a quick example to explain to show you how using variables may fix your issue : https://3v4l.org/cKPP4

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your effort. I've added the variables into my original PHP snippet as i'm not sure that will work with this?

Comment: what's the output you've got ?

Comment: Pasting your snippet directly in results in nothing being output.

Comment: you will need to `echo` the variables to see the output .

Comment: No divs are output either

Comment: update your question with the latest code you are using .

Comment: All sorted now but thank you for your help thus far!